# Drupal 7 upgrade Image module

Tags: 7, media

I was upgrading a site to Drupal 7 but as you may know there are couple of modules which are moved to the core modules in Drupal 7.

I had installed Image and Image Cache module in Drupal 6, but now I am finding it hard to upgrade to Drupal 7. After the upgrade the image doesn't load up.

I also tried migrating the image field, but it says "missing plugin".

Can anyone guide me through the process of upgrading Image and Image Cache module content to Drupal 7.

Answer (score 0):

Over the years, and the major versions, Drupal's image handling has seen more flavours than Baskin Robbins. After my D5->D6 upgrades, I followed what was being talked about for image handling in D7. It allowed me to take a strategic approach to site design in D6 which would, hopefully, improve the compatibility of the site for the next upgrade.

If you are upgrading to D7, your first task is to create a D6 version of your site which is based on functions which are supported by D7. Convert all image handling to imagefield in D6, then your upgrade should go smoothly. If, however, you are still using modiles like [Node Images](http://drupal.org/project/node_images) or [Upload Image](http://drupal.org/project/upload_image) you will have problems because there is no upgrade path.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good guide: [Migrating D6 Content Construction Kit (CCK) to D7 Fields](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/upgrade-to-drupal-7/migrating-d6-content-construction-kit-cck-to-d7-fields)

To summarize:

- [Upgrade core](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/upgrade-to-drupal-7/read-upgradetxt)
- Download CCK for Drupal 7
- Enable CCK Content Migrate
- Browse to the migrate fields page
- Follow instructions

You might need to manually copy some configurations, but that should be it.