# "Content manager: broken/missing"

Tags: 7, views, upgrading

After upgrading to Drupal 7, all the pictures of the items have disappeared.
In the View UI editor, I cannot add an image content and it says "Content manager: broken/missing".

Help?

Comment: Did you tried to upload a new image in D7 and see if the files are uploaded at the same place?

Comment: Were your D6 images in imagefields? If not the D6 site should have first been upgraded to use imagefields in D6, then converted to D7. Have a look at this [question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/65060/drupal-7-upgrade-image-module/65064#65064).

Answer (score 0):

"broken/missing" means that Views can't find the field. If you hover over the "broken/missing" link you can look at the address and get a hint of which field it's supposed to be. Once you know which field it is you can remove the broken handler and re-add it to the views output. If it's not available something has gone wrong with the field migration (I assume you did migrate the fields).